# Как вывести по N строк из каждой группы

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите правильно написать запрос, чтоб работал и для новой, и для старой версии. Нужно выводить два самых дорогих товара с каждой категории.

```sql
    select category,name,price
    from products
    where name IN
        (select top 2 price
         from products as temp
         where temp.category = products.category
         order by price desc)
```

```
+----+----------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+
| id |               name               | category | count | price |
+----+----------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Джинсы Mango Lonny 2             |        1 |     3 |  2990 |
|  2 | Куртка Mango Nico 2              |        2 |     2 |  4999 |
|  3 | Платье Love Republic             |        3 |     7 |  3999 |
|  4 | Джинсы Mango Kim2                |        1 |     3 |  2499 |
|  5 | Жилет Zarina                     |        4 |     7 |  2519 |
|  6 | Юбка Mango Park                  |        5 |     0 |  3999 |
|  7 | Джинсы Imajeans                  |        1 |     6 |  1842 |
|  8 | Брюки OLBE                       |        7 |     5 |  2898 |
|  9 | Джинсы Mango Jane2               |        1 |     4 |   200 |
| 10 | Водолазка OPIMU                  |        8 |    12 |  1527 |
| 11 | Косуха Mango                     |        9 |     4 |  9990 |
| 12 | Джинсы Uptown2 (Mango)           |        1 |     7 |  3499 |
| 13 | Жилет FinFlare                   |        4 |     3 |  6999 |
| 14 | Джинсы Mango Soho2               |        1 |     0 |  1999 |
| 15 | Джеггинсы Sasha Rozhdestvenskaya |       10 |     5 |  1691 |
| 16 | Плащ Vfngo SHERLOCK              |       11 |     1 |  6499 |
| 17 | Юбка Katomi                      |        5 |     0 |  3100 |
+----+----------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

```
    ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3 price
    from products' at line 1
```

Comment: top - это MSSql, в mysql LIMIT

Comment: а как то надо сгруппировать как то по двум характеристикам и так лимит делать?

Comment: @timnavigate Позвольте спросить, чем вы картинки в текст преводите?

Comment: @0xdb использую, например, https://www.onlineocr.net/ и другие онлайн конвертеры и затем разбиваю текст в sublime и уже потом форматирую в ascii стиле.

Comment: @timnavigate Спасибо! Неплохо получается, возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На базе Вашего запроса должно сработать что-то вроде:

```
select category,name,price
from products p
where id IN
    (select * FROM (select t.id
     from products as t
     where t.category = p.category
     order by t.price desc
     limit 2
    ) as sub)
```

---

Я бы ещё попробовал через счётчик.
Что-то вроде:

```
select category,name,price
from (
  select category,name,price,
  (@c:=if(@cat=category, @c+1, if(@cat:=category, 1, 1))) i
  from products t
  CROSS JOIN (select @c:=0, @cat:=null) c
  ORDER BY category, price desc
) as p
where p.i <= 2
```

Comment: выводит (
ERROR 1235: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Без fiddle трудно что-то подсказать. Обновил запрос, можно на join переписать, но вслепую довольно трудно :)